# How to change Apple Watch's app language in code?

Tags: localization, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-4

I would like to change Watch OS app language in code. How to do it?
I want to change app's interface orientation to right-to-left if language needs it too. Is it possible? Will it be automatic?

Answer (score 0):

The user is always in control of the system language and preferred app language. To respond to the language they set, use [localizedString(forKey:value:table:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417694-localizedstring). For interfaces displaying right-to-left languages, see [setSemanticContentAttribute(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceobject/1628136-setsemanticcontentattribute).

Comment: Can I force right-to-left if left-to-right language is set using setSemanticContentAttribute(_:)?